# Error converting DateTime to nullable long

Tags: c#, serialization

I am confused and will need someone to explain me how I can do this as I am missing concept here. This below code works as expected but my aim is to send the StartDate in ticks (epoch). I want to convert the datetime in json to ticks in getter setter property and not in the main class. Is that even possible? if so, please explain. Because when I change the DateTime in Employee class to long, it is throwing me the error converting 06/05/2010 06:00:00 AM to nullable long. Thank you in advance.

```
    public class Employee
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        private string _startDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate
        {
            get
            {
                return DateTime.Parse(_startDate);
            }
            set
            {
                _startDate = value.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "{ \"startDate\":\"06/05/2010 06:00:00 AM\", \"FirstName\":\"John\",\"LastName\":\"Smith\"}";
        Employee emp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(input);
        Console.WriteLine($"{emp.FirstName} {emp.LastName}'s start date is {emp.StartDate.ToString()}");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

error out when I do this

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    private string _startDate { get; set; }
    public long? StartDate
    {
        get
        {
            return DateTime.Parse(_startDate).Ticks;
        }
        set
        {
            _startDate = value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you storing `Employee.StartDate` in a `string` backing field rather than just using an auto property (i.e. `public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a fundamental problem with your design:

```
private string _startDate { get; set; }

public long? StartDate
{
    get
    {
        return DateTime.Parse(_startDate).Ticks;
    }
    set
    {
        _startDate = value.ToString();
    }
}
```

When you use the setter you will set the string to be something like `"132332"` but then when you use the getter you will not be able to parse that value as a DateTime - it is not a valid datetime format.

One fix would be to change the property to this:

```
public long? StartDate
{
    get
    {
        return DateTime.Parse(_startDate).Ticks;
    }
    set
    {
        _startDate = new DateTime(value ?? 0).ToString();
    }
}
```

I believe you can achieve something like what you are setting out to do with the following code, using Serialization attributes and a DateTime backing field:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "{ \"startDate\":\"06/05/2010 06:00:00 AM\", \"FirstName\":\"John\",\"LastName\":\"Smith\"}";
        Employee emp = (Employee)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(input);
        Console.WriteLine($"{emp.FirstName} {emp.LastName}'s start date is {new DateTime(emp.StartDate ?? 0)}");
    }
}

public class Employee
{        
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("startDate")]
    private DateTime _startDate { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public long? StartDate
    {
        get
        {
            return _startDate.Ticks;
        }
        set
        {
            _startDate = new DateTime(value ?? 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you tried changing your StartDate property to long, I'm assuming you're expecting the JSON to neither be the Microsoft nor Javascript notation similar to Date(123345) or new Date(12345) and just the epoch.

This is all you need to do:

```
    public class Employee
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [JsonConverter(typeof(UnixDateTimeConverter))]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "{ \"startDate\": 1591399624, \"FirstName\":\"John\",\"LastName\":\"Smith\"}";

        Employee emp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(input);
        Console.WriteLine($"{emp.FirstName} {emp.LastName}'s start date is {emp.StartDate.ToString()}");

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emp);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        Console.ReadLine();            
    }
```

The output will look like this:

```
John Smith's start date is 6/5/2020 11:27:04 PM
{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Smith","StartDate":1591399624}
```